# Finding distance between point layer and matching polygon layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, proximity

I have two points (GPS photo coordinates) per polygon (area photo is taken).
The two points have an identifier that links both to their corresponding polygon, so I already know each polygon will have two corresponding points. This is just to make sure the photos' gps points are within a reasonable distance of the polygon (like 500ft). I do not care if they are closer to one polygon than another, I just need to ensure the photo gps points are somewhat near their respective polygon.

I have several thousand cases of this and am using ArcGIS Pro. I have been toying with the near tool, but it seems it will just find the nearest feature, whether or not it shares the correct attributes.

Is there another tool I could utilize to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The [Generate Near Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) should assist you to meet your requirement (with my bolding):

> Calculates distances and other proximity information between features
> in one or more feature class or layer. Unlike the Near tool, which
> modifies the input, Generate Near Table writes results to a new
> stand-alone table and s**upports finding more than one near feature**.

This tool [can be used at all license levels in ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm#L_) (unlike in ArcMap which requires an Advanced level license).